# module 'google.cloud.logging_v2' has no attribute 'Client'

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-logging

I'm trying to create log-based metrics programmatically with cloud functions. I didn't really find any code sample so I'm a bit lost. This is the code I have so far

```
from google.cloud import logging_v2

    metric = {"name":"test","filter":"stuff_here"}
    client = logging_v2.Client()
    client.create(metric)
```

I have the following error `module 'google.cloud.logging_v2' has no attribute 'Client'`

#edit

I found some code example in the documentation:

```
metric = client.metric(metric_name, filter_=filter, description=description)
assert not metric.exists()  # API call
metric.create()  # API call
assert metric.exists()  # API call
```

but still stuck with the same error

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, it does not, see [`Client`](https://googleapis.dev/python/logging/latest/client.html)

But, `Client` has a `metric` method that "Creates a metric bound to the current client."

And there's a [`Metrics`](https://googleapis.dev/python/logging/latest/metric.html) class

```
import os

from google.cloud import logging_v2


client = logging_v2.Client(project=os.getenv("PROJECT"))

# You need to provide a filter
# This one counts the Service Accounts created in my project
filter=(
  "resource.type=\"service_account\" "
  "protoPayload.methodName=\"google.iam.admin.v1.CreateServiceAccountKey\" "
  "severity=\"NOTICE\""

)

metric_name=os.getenv("METRIC")
```

And either using `client.metric`:

```
metric = client.metric(
  metric_name,
  filter_=filter,
  description="test")
```

Or using `logging_v2.Metric(...).create()`:

```
metric = logging_v2.Metric(
  metric_name,
  filter_=filter,
  client=client).create()
```

And:

```
print(metric)
```

And:

```sh
export PROJECT=[[YOUR-PROJECT]]
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/you/key.json
export METRIC="test"

# Before
gcloud logging metrics list \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--filter="name=${METRIC}"
Listed 0 items.

python3 python/main.py

# After
gcloud logging metrics list \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--filter="name=${METRIC}" \
--format="yaml(name,filter)"
```

Yields:

```
filter: resource.type="service_account" protoPayload.methodName="google.iam.admin.v1.CreateServiceAccountKey" severity="NOTICE"
name: test
```

Comment: I kind of understand what you mean but what are the implication for my code exactly?

Comment: Added to answer

Answer (score 0):

client should be called like this `client = logging_v2.client.Client()`

for example:

```
client = logging_v2.client.Client()
metric = client.metric(metric_name, filter_=filter, description=description)
assert not metric.exists()  # API call
metric.create()  # API call
assert metric.exists()  # API call
```